# Cohen-Macaulay over a tensor product of rings

Tags: commutative-algebra, cohen-macaulay

Let $A, B, C$ be Noetherian Rings such that $A$ is a subring of $B$ and there exists a ring homomorphism $A \rightarrow C$. Let $M$ be a $(B,C)$ bimodule, i.e. $M$ is both a $B$-module and a $C$-module. Then $M$ is also an $A$-module.

> Question 1: If $M$ is Cohen-Macaulay as an $A$-module, as a $B$-module and as a $C$-module, then is $M$ Cohen-Macaulay as a $B \otimes_A C$ module?
>
> Question 2: Are there any known conditions for $M$ to be Cohen-Macaulay as a $B \otimes_A C$ module?

PS: Remark this question is motivated by my previous question: [showing Cohen-Macaulay property is preserved under a ring extension](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/735297/showing-cohen-macaulay-property-is-preserved-under-a-ring-extension)

Comment: I'm confused.  Isn't it possible that your setup could force $M$ to have two *different* $A$-module structures (one from restriction of scalars from the map $A \subseteq C$, the other from restriction of scalars of $B$ to its subring $A$)?  If so, then your question is ambiguous.

Comment: @neilme: That's a good point. I suppose that we should ask that the two $A$-module structures then coincide.